# Ant + javac + WebDriver: "cannot find symbol: variable By"

Tags: java, ant, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, javac

I have the following TestBase.java:

```
package com.example.tests;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class TestBase {

  protected WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeMethod
  @Parameters("hubAddress")
  public void startDriver(String hubAddress) throws MalformedURLException {
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubAddress), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void stopDriver() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
  }

}
```

And the following Test5.java that extends TestBase:

```
package com.example.tests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.lang.Thread;

@Test
public class Test5 extends TestBase {

  public void test5() {

    driver.get("https://10.20.44.16/main/");


    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("loginUserName")).sendKeys("User5");


  }

}
```

My Ant config (build.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="LoadTest">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.6"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.6"/>
    <path id="Selenium.classpath">
        <pathelement location="C:\Lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar"/>
    </path>
    <path id="LoadTest.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <path refid="Selenium.classpath"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="init" name="build">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="LoadTest.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="Selenium.classpath"/>
    <target name="run-tests" depends="build">
        <testng classpathref="LoadTest.classpath">
            <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml"/>
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run "ant run-tests", I get the following error:

```
[javac] C:\LoadTest\src\com\example\tests\Test5.java:21: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable By
```

So, I don't understand the reaason for this error. The command above ...

```
driver.get("https://10.20.44.16/main/");
```

... works, so I guess all is fine with CLASSPATH.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Racoon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `import org.openqa.selenium.By;` in Test5.Java.

Comment: Still, you need to import it in Test5.java

Comment: Thanks, it works! Still, I don't understand why on Earth I had to do it exactly fo selenium.By and not for selenium.WebDriver.

Comment: You don't use the name `WebDriver` in Test5, only `driver` (which is inherited). Using the type indirectly is fine; import is all about names.

Comment: BTW a good IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc) will handle all the imports for you - which is really useful because otherwise they're pretty tedious.